# No funciona selecction de primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hola amigos tengo un datatable de primefaces con la funcionalidad de selection pero no me funciona,entra al metodo rowSelect(), pero el en event llego el object nulo. Adjunto codigo que tengo implementado, si alguien sabe que pasa porfa ayudeme:

```
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{dialogCuentasContablesController.rowSelect}"/>


        </p:dataTable>
```

///bean
public void rowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        ConPlantasDto conPlantas = (ConPlantasDto) event.getObject();
        setCuentaContable(conPlantas);
    }

Comment: Por favor, agregue el dato completo de la tabla, ya que hay configuraciones ahí que deben ser tenidas en cuenta

Comment: Sugiero mirar https://goo.gl/LiNj7g, están todos los ejemplos con todo el detalle.